# .htaccess rewrite for passing parameters

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like change my URL from

`www.example.com/collections.php?id=abc123` to `www.example.com/collections/abc123`

I use `.htaccess` like this:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^collections/(\w+)/?$ collections.php?id=$1 [QSA,L,NC] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Now, when I type `www.example.com/collections/abc123` in browser, my webpage shows without loading any css files or script. 
can someone point out what is missing ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` doesn't make sense. You don't need it. You need `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`. so if the filename is not an existing directory and not an existing file apply the following rule. the `\.php` is too much

Comment: For your problem: check the apache error log. There should be a hint in it.

Comment: add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently you're using a relative path in referencing your scripts. So, what's happening is your browser is attempting to fetch those resources wrongly because of that additional `/` in the url, causing it to think you navigated to a different directory.
What you could do here is specify absolute paths instead.

An example would be `http://example.com/css/style.css` as opposed to `/css/style.css`